# Solidity The called function should be payable, but it's view function

Tags: arrays, mapping, solidity

If I add one item to my mapping array, I get this error: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance,

but my function is on view. I cannot make it payable. Also doesn't seem like I added too much logic there. What am I doing wrong?

```
    mapping(address => uint256[]) public owns;

function checkInventory() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        require(owns[msg.sender].length != 0, "Inventory is empty");
        uint256[] memory inventory;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < owns[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            inventory[i] = owns[msg.sender][i];
        }
        return (inventory);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the revert message is a bit misleading to those new to the language. The real problem you are having is that you are getting an `index out of bounds` error.

You should initialize your inventory with enough length.

```
function checkInventory() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        require(owns[msg.sender].length != 0, "Inventory is empty");
        uint256[] memory inventory = new uint256[](owns[msg.sender].length); // here is the problem
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < owns[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            inventory[i] = owns[msg.sender][i];
        }
        return (inventory);
    }
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey @Burtininkas, would appreciate if you can accept and upvote my answer